# How do I manage remote WebFarms using c#?

Tags: c#, .net, iis, web-farm-framework

I am trying to write a utility to add / remove servers from webfarms on remote IIS instances in C#.

I am trying to find something equivalent to ServerManager.OpenRemote("MachineName") which is available in Microsoft.Web.Administration; I originally tried using this library to manage webfarms but am having a lot of trouble modifying server collections.

So, I added a reference to Microsoft.Web.Farm.dll in my .net project. I now have access to the "WebFarmManager" class and can get access to those farms on the local machine.

How can i use WebFarmManager to get access to farms on a remote machine?